# Python, subprocess, filepath white spaces and famous 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Enclosing a full file path inside the "" quotes does not make it work.

**cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes\iTunes.exe"**

**subprocess.popen** throws an error of not being able to find an executable if there is a white space in a file-path to be executed.

A while ago I was able to find a solution which involved a use of some weird symbols or their combination... Unfortunately I can't locate a code with that example. I would appreciate if someone would point me in a right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the white space and not with the backslashes? Try `cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\iTunes\\iTunes.exe"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslashes in strings trigger escape characters. Since Windows fully supports the use of the forward slash as a path separator, just do that:

```
cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/iTunes/iTunes.exe"
```

No need to fiddle around with `\\` or raw strings. ;)

Comment: Windows doesn't support unquoted and un-escaped spaces. :(

Comment: So what, does Popen always use the shell (or whatever the equivalent is) to open external programs on Windows, even with ``shell=False``? In that case, the fix is easy: just add quotes. ``cmd = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/iTunes/iTunes.exe"'``

Comment: Without a windows machine to hand I was reluctant to suggest this without testing as it is Python for Windows that supports forward slashes in file paths rather than windows and I suspected that the nested quotes could possibly defeat this.

Answer (score 2):

Either use:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\iTunes\\iTunes.exe"'
```

or

```
cmd = r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunesr\iTunes.exe"'
```

Comment: cmd = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\iTunes\\iTunes.exe"' won't work.

Comment: I am not sure about r'  "c:\\Program Files\\executable.exe    '

Comment: @Sputnix 1) the first won't work or doesn't work?  2) so try it.

Answer (score 1):

the file path：

```
file_path= 'E:\\te st.py'
```

then you should:

```
file_path = '"E:\\te st.py"'
```

then it works, my Main.py as show blow:

```
import subprocess

doc = '"E:\\te st.py"'

p = subprocess.Popen ('python ' + doc , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()
print output
```

and the te st.py is:

```
print 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape your cmd line: replace

```
"\"
```

by

```
"\\"
```

And

```
' '
```

(space) by

```
'\ '
```

(backslash + space).